# How to divide a graph into two sets having maximum interset connection?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a undirected graph , i want to divide it into two group in which intergroup connections are maximum and connection in same group are as minimum as possible.

Comment: You give two different criteria to be optimised (between-group connections are to be maximised, within-group connections are to be minimised), and no clear way to decide which is more important, so in my answer I've assumed that the former is more important.

Comment: Intergroup connections are to be maximized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called [Maximum Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut).  Unfortunately it's NP-hard, so don't expect a fast algorithm for large instances.